# Client receives only some server sent events

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, react-native, expo, server-sent-events

I am working with server sent events with spring boot in the backend and react-native/expo as client. 
To handle server send event on the client I use [react-native-event-source](https://github.com/jordanbyron/react-native-event-source). But the problem is only some events are received by the client. Here is the scenario:

- event id 0 -> not received
- event id 1 -> received
- event id 2 -> not received
- event id 3 -> received
- event id 4 -> not received
- event id 5 -> received
  ...

on the server side we tried deferent hacks and logs show that the server is actually sending each event but the expo client seems to ignore some events (1 event in two).

Here is how we initialize connection to get server sent events:

```
  listen() {
    const options = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.userToken}`,
      },
    };
    let url = `${TEST_URL}${this.user.id}`;
    try {
      console.log('starting stream ...');

      const eventName = `dataSet-created${this.user.id}`;

      this.eventSource = new RNEventSource(url, options); 
      this.eventSource.addEventListener(eventName, event => {
        console.log('stream event received', event);
      });

      this.eventSource.addEventListener('error', e => {
        console.log('stream listener error', e);
      });

      console.log('eventSource stream ...', this.eventSource);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('start stream error', e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-native-event-source` does not use true EventSource but rather works around by polling. So my guess is your client miss messages because there are multiple in single polling interval ([that is 500ms](https://github.com/jordanbyron/react-native-event-source/blob/master/EventSource.js#L11)).

Reason for this is react native [currently does not support HTTP streams](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12912).